# Java count occurrence of each element in an integer array

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've written the following snippet to count the number of occurrences of each element. Is it possible to achieve this in a much shorter way?

```
int[] arr = {1, 6, 2, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 7};
Arrays.stream(arr)
        .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll)
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
        .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k+" "+v.size()));
```

Also I would like to display only the elements which occur more than 1 time. So I tried modifying as below which resulted in an error.

```
.forEach((k, v) -> if(v.size() > 1) System.out.println(k+" "+v.size()));
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the latter question, you have to change

```
.forEach((k, v) -> if(v.size() > 1) System.out.println(k+" "+v.size()));
```

to

```
.forEach((k, v) -> {if(v.size() > 1) System.out.println(k+" "+v.size());});
```

For the first part, it's not clear why you need the first `collect` followed by a second `Stream` pipeline.
If the purpose was to convert an `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>`, use `boxed()`:

```
Arrays.stream(arr)
      .boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
      .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k+" "+v.size()));
```

As Dici suggested, you can also chain Collectors to group each number with its number of occurrences :

```
Map<Integer,Integer> occurrences = 
    Arrays.stream(arr)
          .boxed()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: There's a slighlty better way using `Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())`. With a bunch of static imports it looks nicer

Comment: Also is it possible to return the result as a Map<Integer, Integer> instead of printing it?

Comment: @DhiwaTdG Yes, you can use Dici's suggestion.

Comment: I tried that but it returns all the values whereas I wish to return only the elements which occur more than one time.

Comment: @DhiwaTdG You might have to run that Map through another Stream pipeline to filter out the numbers having a single occurrence. I'm not sure whether you can do that in the same Stream pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to using a third-party library, [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) has a `Bag` type which can be used as follows:

```
Bags.mutable.with(1, 6, 2, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 7)
    .selectDuplicates()
    .forEachWithOccurrences((k, count) -> System.out.println(k+" "+count));
```

If you have to keep `int[] arr` variable as an int array, then you can use an `IntBag` as follows:

```
IntBags.mutable.with(arr)
    .selectDuplicates()
    .forEachWithOccurrences((k, count) -> System.out.println(k+" "+count));
```

`IntBag` is a primitive collection so does not box the `int` values into `Integer` wrappers.

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Integer> numsList=Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,2,4,3,1,2,2,4,4,5);
Map<Integer, Long> map=numsList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::intValue,Collectors.counting()));
map.forEach((k,v)->{System.out.println(k+" = "+v);});
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my solution as well!!!

```
// Solution 1 [Improved from Eran's solution & suggestion]
int[] arr = {1, 6, 2, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 7};
Map<Integer, Long> counts = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .boxed()
    .collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(n -> n, counting()),
        map -> map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(n -> n.getValue() > 1)
            .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue))
));
System.out.println(counts.toString());

// Solution 2 [Improved from Dici's suggestion]
int[] arr = {1, 6, 2, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 7};
Map<Object, Long> counts = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll)
    .stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));
counts.values().removeIf(count -> count < 2);
System.out.println(counts.toString());
```

Comment: Note that by `groupingBy` specification it's not guaranteed that returned map will be mutable. So such solution may fail in future Java (or non-OpenJDK-based) implementations.

Comment: You can easily solve the issue mentioned by @Tagir by using `.collect(groupingBy( Function.identity(), HashMap::new, counting()));`. Then, the result in guaranteed to be a mutable `HashMap` and you can use `removeIf`. Note that this also works together with `collectingAndThen`. By the way, you don’t need `toString()` when using `System.out.println`…

Answer (score 0):

Also might be done using frequency :

```
 List<Integer> list = ImmutableList.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5);
 Map<Integer, Integer> result = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), token -> Collections.frequency(list, token)));
```